# Unicode & Ruby - Expected behavior?

Tags: ruby, unicode, emoji, irb

Ruby Version: ruby 2.2.2p95 (2015-04-13 revision 50295) [x86_64-darwin14]

Readline Version: 6.2

I'm working with some emojis and many of them behave correctly with the exception of 2. The  and  emojis. Here is some terminal output:

```
(byebug) ""
"\u{1F32D}"
(byebug) ""
""
(byebug) ""
"\u{1F37E}"
```

Can someone tell me what's going on here? Is it just some encoding screwiness with irb? I might be snow-blind since I've been wrestling with this for so long so if there's any more information required to answer this please let me know.

Comment: This might depend on the capabilities of your terminal more than Ruby itself. Remember that `"\u{....}"` is a valid representation of a UTF-8 character, it's like `\n`. What happens if you `puts` those?

Comment: @tadman `puts ""` does actually print the  to stdout. This may just work for what I'm trying to do then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ruby may show a string with various *backslash* encodings for various reasons, one of which is irregular characters. For example:

```
"
"
# => "\n"
'"'
# => "\""
```

This doesn't mean the string contains an actual backslash, but rather that the version shown by `inspect` contains one. This is a long tradition dating back at least to the era of C in the 1970s where `\n` and such have been understood to mean "newline character".

In the case of emoji you might find that some are displayed and others aren't. This may be an interaction between the version of Ruby you're using and the terminal settings. As emoji are constantly being introduced you might find older ones display properly but Ruby's not confident enough with new ones to render them as-is, perhaps concerned that's an invalid Unicode character. Rather than showing something blank or the infamous *question mark* character, it shows the literal code for the character.

Comment: "As emoji are constantly being introduced..." Indeed, both  and  were introduced in Unicode 8.0 (June 2015), which was not supported by Ruby [until version 2.3](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_3_0/NEWS#L141).